# Are $Z$ and $B$ independent Brownian Motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

Let's consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ and a filtration for this space $\Bbb F:=(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$.

Let's consider a Brownian Motion $B=(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ and the stopping time defined by $\tau_a:=\inf\{s\ge0\;:\;B_s=a\}$ where $a>0$, both with respect to $\Bbb F$.

Let's then set $\mathcal G_t:=\mathcal F_{t+\tau_a}$, where
$\mathcal G_{t+\tau_a}:=\{A\in\mathcal A\;:\; A\cap\{t+\tau_a\le s\}\in\mathcal F_s\;\;\forall s\ge0\}$
; thus $\Bbb G:=(\mathcal G_t)_{t\ge0}$ is another filtration.
:
Now it is well known (by a theorem of Markov) that $Z_t:=B_{t+\tau_a}-B_{\tau_a}$ is a Brownian Motion with respect to $\Bbb G$.

Now I would like to prove or disprove the independence of $B$ and $Z$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Can someone give me an hint please?

Many thanks.

Comment: What kind of object should $\mathcal{G}_t$ be? $\mathcal{G}_t$ depends on $\omega\in\Omega$ because $\tau_a$ does, so $\mathbb{G}$ is not a filtration on your given probability space and so $Z_t$ cannot be a BM w.r.t. to it.

Comment: $Z$ and $B$ are not independent. Just notice that $\sigma(Z)\subset\sigma(B)$. What is true is that $\sigma(Z)$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{\tau_a}$.

Comment: @Gono: I edited; however I think my notation is standard

Comment: Thx for edit :-) And yeah, you're right. It's standard.

Comment: Can I know the reason for the downvote?